# HTML - JS - if instagram is selected and the textbox is opened, the textbox must be filled

Tags: javascript, php, html

hi guys i have a request from y'all thanks in advance. if instagram is selected on my select box, and the text box is opened, the textbox must be filled.

I added "required" to input options, the code works but instagram asks you to enter text in textbox even if it is not selected.

```
<a><b>The Platform You Order:</b></a>         
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectdiv2" id="selection2" name="platform" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="WhatsApp">WhatsApp</option>
    <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
</select>
                               
<div id="iii" style="display:none;">
    <br>
    <input class="input1" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Instagram Username:" type='radio' data-target='select_raido3' class='myRadioooo' > 
</div>
        
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#selection2').on('change', function()
    {                       
        if (this.value == 'Instagram')
        {
            $("#iii").show();
        }else{
            $("#iii").hide();
            $('.mySelect2').hide();
        }
    });

    $('.myRadioooo').click(function(){
        $('.mySelect2').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: fyi, your input has `type="text"` **and** `type='radio'`

Comment: using "required" as an attribute will require it all the time. Before your data is submitted, check to see if Instagram is selected and if the textbox is opened, and if the textbox value is blank. If so, stop the submit, let the user know what's needed.

Comment: so, what should I do??